# Update Loop in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a screen class in libGDX.  In this screen, I want to change a sprite's texture a certain number of times before the screen changes to a different screen class.  I tried having a for loop in the render method, but that obviously didn't work as render is constantly called.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private long time;

public void show(){
//...
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();

}
public void draw(){
//...
       if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time+3000){
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("called after 3 seconds");
            //change texture
        }
}
```

So you can change your `Sprite`'s `Texture` every 3 seconds.